# Disguise executable as image

Tags: linux, jpeg, hidden, mime

///NOTHING ILLEGAL! READ PLEASE BEFORE VOTING FOR CLOSING///

I have a project where i need to run a 4 Mb file on a tp-link router. This router has a 4Mb flash (300 kb left after openwrt is installed) so the file wont fit into the memory and i have to re-uplaod the file each time. I would like to automate this, by downloading the file from the attached photocamera as soon as the file is found. The problem is that the camera when connected via PTP protocol hides all files that are not known, (jpg, cr2, etc..) and also hides all folders that do not match its naming structure (100Canon, 101Canon etc..)

I would need a way to make the camera think that the file is an image file so it displays it when the camera is connected via PTP. I already tried renaming it to .jpg but it didnt work. Googled for changing the mime type but doesnt seem to be possible as it is tied to the system and not the file itself.

Thanks

Comment: This question is simply off-topic as it has nothing to do with programming.

Comment: it has nothing to do with any of the stackexchange sites directly.. but since you need to know programming basics in order to solve this problem  i think that this is the place where it fits best.. Phogographers wouldnt have the knowhow on how to approach this,but programmers do.

Comment: You want to convince a device of unknown make and model to treat an executable file as a jpeg image. That's not programming. If it's programming, show some code that you think might be able to do it. Where would you run this code? What programming language would you use?

Comment: as I said, its NOT programming, but to solve the problem you need a programmer's knowledge. the people who have the knowledge to solve this are on stackoverflow, and not on any other branch of stackexchange. so even if it is not directly about programming, this is the only place i can post it..